# Not able to fetch headers via AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, header, request, cross-domain

I have added the following to server-side API.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: temp');
header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: temp');
header('temp: 12345');
```

When I am making a `cURL` request to the API, I get the headers along with the response-data.

But when I am making an `AJAX` call to the same API, I only get the data, without the header.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Anish

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the headers in an AJAX request by calling the `getAllResponseHeaders()` method on the XHR object. The reference is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)